# Помогите найти алгоритм решения задачи

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Имеется исходный массив положительных чисел, `N` — число новых массивов, `Mi` – максимальная сумма в текущем массиве. Нужно распределить все числа из заданного массива на `N` массивов так, чтобы сумма чисел в каждом массиве была максимальна близка к заданной `Mi`. Найти оптимальный вариант распределения.

Я уверен, что должен быть готовый алгоритм подобной задачи. Что-то из разряда комбинаторной оптимизации может быть. Перебор не предлагать

Comment: Условия задачи точно корректно написал?

Comment: Да. Mi может быть свое для каждого массива

Comment: в новых массивах может быть использовано одновременно одно и то же число из исходного массива?

Comment: Классическая "задача о рюкзаке". И решения тоже классические.

Comment: @Akina, перебор? :-)

Comment: Ну задача NP-полная, так что если решать влоб, то да. Но есть несколько алгоритмов, изрядно оптимизирующих поиск, особенно если имеются какие-то ограничения или особенности. К тому же условие ЭТОЙ задачи не требует найти оптимум (если таковой в ней вообще определён), достаточно решения, близкого к оптимуму - а тут для оптимизации поля непаханые...

Comment: Думаю, что даже жадного алгоритма будет достаточно, особенно если разность между суммой элементов исходного массива и суммой пределов конечных массивов велика.

Comment: @Grundy, число из исходного массива может быть использована только 1 раз

Comment: @Akina, Задача о рюкзаке и жадный алгоритм подразумевают вес. А у меня ведь его нет, да и "рюкзаков" много, и распределить нужно обязательно все числа

Comment: У Вас просто вырожденная задача, когда все веса равны единице.

Comment: Метод "ветвей и границ"

Answer (score 1):

1. Если общее количество чисел равно N*Mi, то в качестве критерия оптимальности можно принять минимум суммы квадратов отклонений фактического Mi от требуемого.
2. Заполнять каждый массив следует от больших чисел к меньшим ("жадный" алгоритм), рассматривая варианты с перебором и недобором по каждому массиву.
3. Не думаю, что за обозримое время можно достичь большего даже при относительно небольших массивах.